# FlexLayoutModule Not working in other modules

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I have imported FlexLayoutModule in all modules but still not working in the dashboard component.

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="main-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Dashboard Component</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "still not working"? Please share more details and / or error outputs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.